# Why does the accordion works just once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to get this effect:

[image]

When I open the dialog for the first time everything works fine.
But if I close the dialog and open it again this is what I see:

[image]

Does someone knows how to fix it?
This is the part of my code:

```
function showLicenses(cluster_id) {
    // get licenses from window object
  var licenses = window.licenses[cluster_id];
    $('#accordion-cluster').html('');
  // sort reverse timestamp
  licenses = licenses.sort(function(a, b){
    return new Date(b.date_created) - new Date(a.date_created);
  });

  $.each(licenses, function(index, license){
    console.log(license);
    var id = license.license_id;
    var licenseNo = index + 1;
    if(licenseNo !== 1){
      //$("#accordion-cluster").append('<hr><br>')
    }
    $("#accordion-cluster").append('<h2> LICENSE ' + licenseNo + '<a class="removeLicense" style="background:#c8212f;color:white;padding:5px;margin:15px;position:absolute;top: 0;right: 0;" data-license-id="' + license.license_id + '">remove</a></h2><div>' + license.key_contents + '</div>');
  });
  $("#dialog").dialog({
      height: 500,
      width: 800,
      modal: true,
      open: function(){
          var icons = {
              header: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",    // custom icon class
              activeHeader: "ui-icon-triangle-1-n" // custom icon class
          };
          console.log($("#accordion-cluster"));
          $("#accordion-cluster").accordion({
              collapsible : true,
              active : 'none',
              icons: icons
          });
      }
  });
  $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="License Key">
    <div style="white-space: pre-wrap;" id="license-key">
         <div id="accordion-cluster">

         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To answer to the comments, this is the appearance of the opened accordion (just the first time i open the dialog box):

[image]

Comment: Can you show how it looks when you open it first time? Because we can not see difference what it looks at first and what with 2nd view.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay The first image shows the first time, the accordion is working. The second image shows when reopening, the accordion is not working

Comment: Hi @HimanshuUpadhyay. The first print screen is the first time. So it's exactly what i need. The second time instead is the second print screen that you see. The structure of the html is the correct one, but accordion is not working.

Comment: It seems like 2nd time all accordions are open?

Comment: Nope. The accordion is not working at all. If they were opened they should look like this (i add a new print screen in the question)

Comment: New image added. This is the correct opened accordion. And it works perfectly when accordion works.
I don't really know why the second time i open the dialog box the accordion function isn't fired.

Comment: Can you include the window.licenses part?

Comment: Could it be that you have a missing tag somewhere and when you are using the accordion, the html is altered and that has an impact where there is malformed html?

Comment: @RickJelier window.licences is just the json that is printed inside the opened accordion. I think that the problem should be somewhere else. Like it's not firing the accordion function the second time.

Comment: @karen could be, but if that was the reason normally it should not work also the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to destroy the accordion before changing the data inside, the best timing to do this is when closing the dialog:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    height: 500,
    width: 800,
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        var icons = {
            header: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",    // custom icon class
            activeHeader: "ui-icon-triangle-1-n" // custom icon class
        };

        $("#accordion-cluster").accordion({
            collapsible : true,
            active : 'none',
            icons: icons
        });
    },
    close: function () {
        $('#accordion-cluster').accordion('destroy');
    }
});
```

Related question that helped me: [re-initialize jquery accordion on callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301783/re-initialize-jquery-accordion-on-callback)
Do note that the referenced question is **not** a duplicate, because of the fact this question involves a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

**It doesn't make sense to destroy and create the view every time a user clicks it.** It may work for a small scale solution but you should definitely use the [JQueryUI accordion API](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) according to the specs:

Initiate the accordion div on pageload using:

```
$('#accordion').accordion()
```

Then on any change call:

`$('#accordion').accordion( "refresh" )`

Check out the [Docs for refresh](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh)